# Am I taking the right approach in PHP OOP?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

Trying to make the switch over to OOP PHP as opposed to my current approach of having a whole load of PHP code in all of my pages.

I've thrown something together which takes a post title, content and status and stores it in a simple database.

I just want to know if I have the right idea or if I'm way off - is it worth me carrying on taking this approach on it?

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','','admin');

class post {
    private $title;
    private $content;
    private $status;
    private $errors;
    private $check;

    function __construct(){
        if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){

            if(empty($_POST['title'])){
                $this->errors[] = "Title is required";
            }

            if(empty($_POST['content'])){
                $this->errors[] = "Content is required";
            }

            if(empty($_POST['status'])){
                $this->errors[] = "Status is required";
            }

            if(empty($this->errors)){
                $this->title = $_POST['title'];
                $this->content = $_POST['content'];
                $this->status = $_POST['status'];
                $this->check = true;
            } else {
                echo "<pre>";
                var_dump($this->errors);
                echo "</pre>";
            }
        }
    }

    function submit(){
        if($this->check){
            global $conn;

            if($conn->connect_error){
                die("Connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
            };

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (title, content, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

            $stmt->bind_param('sss', $this->title, $this->content, $this->status);

            if($stmt->execute()){
                echo "Post added succesfully";
            } else {
                echo "<pre>";
                var_dump($stmt);
                echo "</pre>";
            }

        };
    }
};

?>
```

Comment: this belongs on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Currently the right approach would be using 'Composer' to load your files & an ORM to interact with your database something like ``Illuminate Database`` where you just extend from a Model & leave the rest of your file empty. https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/database or just use a frame-work & save yourself the hassle of having to wire things manually

Comment: Dagon is right, you should submit it to code review.

But, answering your question:

So you wrote a class. Congratulations, its the first step to OO. 
You now know how write a class and create an object. Now learn about MVC and you will start programming in OO in some moment.

Comment: Now let's analyze your code:
First if of the constructor has the fragment:
&& !empty($_POST)
So all the ifs will evaluate as false. Only the else at the end of the constructor method will be executed.

Comment: This has nothing to do with OOP. You are using globals everywhere. The class has multiple responsibilities. You are `echo`ing out data.